# Can I call street dogs “strays”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m from germany ^^
Thanks for answers

Comment: Please include the research you have done.

Answer (score 2):

[Stray](https://www.yourdictionary.com/stray) is an adjective:

> the definition of stray is someone or something that has been separated from where it should be or that is loose and all-by-itself.
>
> - A dog that has no home is an example of a dog that would be described as a stray dog.

(YourDictionary.com)

and also a noun:

***[stray](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/stray)***
noun [ C ]  (LOST ANIMAL)

> an animal that is lost or has no home:
>
> - We have given a home to a number of strays.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: But the single word "stray", (or "strays"), meaning "stray dog", or "stray cat" has become everyday idiomatic. At least that is the case in Britain.